# How to enforce navigation animation in the parent frame after the child frame has navigated?

Tags: c#, xaml, animation, uwp

My app has 2 nested frames in this hierarchy:

`Window` > `Frame` (root frame) > `Page` (root page) > `Frame` (inner frame) > `Page` (inner page).

The root frame implements navigation transition animation in its constructor, in App.xaml.cs.

```
rootFrame = new Frame()
            { ContentTransitions = new TransitionCollection
            { new NavigationThemeTransition() }};
```

The inner frame implements the same animation in XAML.

```
<Frame>
    <Frame.ContentTransitions>
        <TransitionCollection>
            <NavigationThemeTransition />
        </TransitionCollection>
    </Frame.ContentTransitions>
</Frame>
```

When the root frame navigates to a root page, the animation works. However, the navigation animation of the root frame stops working after the inner frame navigates to an inner page.

I have tried to implement the animation for the child frame in code instead of XAML, but with no influence on the result.

How to make the root frame navigation animation to work after the inner frame navigates to an inner page?

Comment: what is the expected behaviour? after the inner frame navigates to an inner page, do you expect there is a transition in the root page too?

Comment: I expect the navigation animation for the root frame to occur when navigating to a root page. Currently this doesn't happen **after** the inner frame navigates. I don't expect both frames to perform the animation while only the inner frame navigates.

Comment: I can not reproduce your issue, the NavigationThemeTransition can works even the inner frame navigate to inner page.